# Is it possible to store java compilation result in RAM instead of Hard Disk?

Tags: java, 64-bit, nasm

suppose this is a simple java program:-

```
//FileName: Temp.java
class Temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Java");
    }
}
```

To execute above code we have to command as :-

`javac Temp.java`  // After compilation we get Temp.class(stored in same directory)

`java Temp.class`

So, I wanted to write a program in NASM(Linux,64 Bit) which gets input file(.java) via command line and store the result of compiler(javac) in RAM itself and execute program via `java` command by providing memory address to java command.

I found `system()` gcc function to execute the command line. But, I have no clue how to store `javac` result in RAM itself and execute java program by providing memory address to `java` command to execute java program.

Or is there any possible to write such program??

Comment: Today is a **great** day to *learn* about [RAM drives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive).

Comment: why do you wan to do that? care to share the requirement?